# Can not get strtr() to work with conversion to text

Tags: php

I have written some code to help me out at work, this converts a string/blob of text into something that can be used as metadata.

I wrote the following, but only revert works... I am newish to PHP so to me this is baffling as hell!

```
<?php
$text = $_POST['field'];
if(isset($_POST['convert'])){   
    $trans = array("&" => "&amp;", "\"" => "&quot;", "“" => "&quot;", "”" => "&quot;", "'" => "&apos;", "<" => "&lt;", ">" => "&gt;");
} else if(isset($_POST['revert'])){
    $trans = array("&amp;" => "&", "&quot;" => "\"", "&apos;" => "'", "&lt;" => "<", "&gt;" => ">");
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GentetCreations</title>
    <meta name="description" content="website description" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="website keywords, website keywords" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <?php include("inc/pageHead.php"); ?>
        <div id="site_content">
            <?php include("inc/side.php"); ?>
            <div id="content">
                <form method="POST" action="metaConvert.php" id="convertMeta">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <textarea id="field" name="field" rows="20" cols="80" autofocus><?php echo strtr($text, $trans); ?></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p style="padding-top: 15px">
                                    <input class="submit" name="convert" value="Convert" type="submit">
                                    <input class="submit" name="revert" value="Revert" type="submit">
                                </p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include("inc/footer.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a live demo on the website that I have been creating here: [www.gentetcreations.co.uk/metaConvert.php](http://www.gentetcreations.co.uk/metaConvert.php)

Comment: Where and when is used strtr() ?

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/it/function.urlencode.php and http://php.net/manual/it/function.urldecode.php ...

Comment: The provided link does not work with https

Comment: The issue here is; I need the text to convert EXACTLY as it is, for example, if I was to write some .js code, I would need this to convert it to metadata safe as I use SourceTree and Git to push the bulk of text direct so I have no interaction. This then goes through Git for testing and if the format is messed up it's harder to troubleshoot after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code actually works, but you have to html-encode the "unencoded" text to show it "as is". Try this:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(strtr($text, $trans)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) does this conversion

Comment: Same as the above, I need to text to translate exactly as I am doing in the strtr() method, if anything else converts it can mess with the back end of Salesforce (CRM system)